# Echo in heredoc / nowdoc syntax

Tags: php, mysql, email

I've been reading up on the Heredoc and Nowdoc syntax, and I'm trying to understanding how to break out of it so I can add other functionality.

I would like to break out of it after this part (if possible):

```
User::sendNewticket($send_to, 'Maintenance Ticket '.Input::get('st_id'),
```

but throws a syntax error when I add `?>` after `'Maintenance Ticket '.Input::get('st_id'), ?>`

Anyways, I gave up on that for the time being and I would be good to go if I could figure out how to echo the following using this syntax:

```
'.$fn.'<br>
'.$time.'<br>
'.$stc.'<br>
```

Similar to this `echo $fn;`

Here is relevant code to my situation.

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/core/init.php");

// new data
$send_to           = $_POST['send_to'];
$rec_message       = $_POST['rec_message'];

//Message
$status            = $_POST['status'];
$st_id             = $_POST['st_id'];
$posted_by         = $_POST['posted_by'];
$posted_on         = $_POST['posted_on'];
$unit              = $_POST['unit'];
$subject           = $_POST['subject'];
$content           = $_POST['content'];

//Loader & Flash Message
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=/admin/maintenance/email-ticket.php?st_id='.$st_id.'">'; 
Session::flash('email-ticket', '<h3 class="orange-tx" align="center">Your Email has been sent!</h3>');

//Replies
//$id                = $_POST['id'];
//$from_name           = $_POST['from_name'];
//$st_time         = $_POST['st_time'];
//$st_content          = $_POST['st_content'];

//Pulling Conversation from database
$st_messages = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `id`,`st_id`,`from_name`,`st_content`,`st_time` FROM `st_messages` WHERE `st_id` = $st_id ORDER BY id ASC");


foreach ($st_messages->results() as $mt) {
if($mt->from_name=='Support Team'){
} else {
}

$fn = escape ($mt->from_name);
$time = escape (date("F d, Y - h:i a", strtotime ($mt->st_time)));
$stc = nl2br (escape($mt->st_content));

//START EMAIL
User::sendNewticket($send_to, 'Maintenance Ticket '.Input::get('st_id'), 
'Hello -<br><br>
'.Input::get('rec_message').'<br><br>


<strong>Ticket Info:</strong><br><br>

<strong>Status: </strong>'.Input::get('status').'<br>
<strong>Ticket #: </strong>'.Input::get('st_id').'<br>
<strong>Posted By: </strong>'.Input::get('posted_by').'<br>
<strong>Posted On: </strong>'.Input::get('posted_on').'<br>
<strong>Building Unit: </strong>'.Input::get('unit').'<br>
<strong>Subject: </strong>'.Input::get('subject').'<br>
<strong>Ticket Message: </strong>'.Input::get('content').'<br><br>

<strong>Conversation:</strong><br><br>

'.$fn.'<br>
'.$time.'<br>
'.$stc.'<br>
---------------------------------<br><br>


Thank You,<br>
Support Team');
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to do is email a support ticket conversation to one recipient.
Like this:

[image]

I'm getting the "Original Message" from the Message $_POST. And the email address and email message from the New Data $_POST.

**For the Conversation** I'm trying to pull that info from the database table.

My current code emails the conversation, but emails each conversation in multiple emails.

Example, If there are 3 entries in the conversation it sends 3 emails:

- Email 1 contains: Admin reply 1
- Email 2 contains: User reply 1
- Email 3 contains: Admin reply 2

I think if I get the echo working it will group the entire conversation into one email.

**This is an example of the final email output I trying to obtain:**

Hello -

Hey Please view this ticket and take care of the problem.
Thanks

**Ticket Info:**

- Status: OPEN
- Ticket #: 201406016
- Posted By: User Name
- Posted On: June 27, 2014 - 03:46 pm
- Building Unit: D47
- Subject: 1
- Ticket Message: 1

**Conversation:**

Support Team

July 01, 2014 - 09:19 am

Admin reply 1

---

User Name

July 01, 2014 - 09:19 am

User reply 1

---

Support Team

July 01, 2014 - 09:19 am

Admin reply 2

---

Thank You,

Support Team

---

**END Email Example**

Any suggestions would be helpful.

**UPDATE**

I'm starting to understand this a little better. The only error I'm receiving is in my foreach loop not sure how to correct it.

Here is the code:

```
$st_messages = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT `id`,`st_id`,`from_name`,`st_content`,`st_time` FROM `st_messages` WHERE `st_id` = $st_id ORDER BY id ASC");

//START EMAIL
$recMessage = Input::get('rec_message');
User::sendNewticket($send_to, 'Maintenance Ticket '.Input::get('st_id'), <<<TEXT
Hello -<br><br>
$recMessage
TEXT

foreach ($st_messages->results() as $mt) {

$fn = "echo escape ($mt->from_name);";
$time = "echo escape (date(\"F d, Y - h:i a\", strtotime ($mt->st_time)));";
$stc = "echo nl2br (escape($mt->st_content));";
}


<<<TEXT2
<strong>Conversation:</strong><br><br>
 
$fn<br>
$time<br>
$stc<br><br>

Thanks,<br>
Support Team
);
TEXT2

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you were intending to do, it's a bit awkard looking:

```
$fn = escape($mt->from_name);
$time = escape(date("F d, Y - h:i a", strtotime($mt->st_time)));
$stc = nl2br(escape($mt->st_content));

//START EMAIL
User::sendNewticket($send_to, 'Maintenance Ticket ' . Input::get('st_id'), <<<TEXT
Hello -<br><br>
TEXT
        . Input::get('rec_message') . <<<TEXT2
<br><br>

<strong>Conversation:</strong><br><br>

$fn<br>
$time<br>
$stc<br>

TEXT2
);
```

The start of a heredoc **must** be the last thing on a line, so after that you drop down and immediately go into the text block. The end of the heredoc **must** be the only thing on the line, so to concatenate it you have to drop down a line before you can use the operator (`.`). You also don't need to use any quotation marks or append operators when inside a heredoc.

It's so unintuitive in fact, that even the StackOverflow Syntax highlighter gets it wrong, the first `<<<TEXT` works fine when I ran this:

```
$mt = new stdClass();
function escape($v){return $v;}
class User{static function sendNewTicket($a, $b, $c){echo $c;}}
class Input{static function get($a){return 'Got something';}}
$send_to = '';
$mt->from_name = 'Kitty';
$mt->st_time = '5th November';
$mt->st_content = <<<CONTENT
    Dear Judy,

        Lorem Dipsum and all that jazz.

        Toodles,
            Kitty.
CONTENT;

$fn = escape($mt->from_name);
$time = escape(date("F d, Y - h:i a", strtotime($mt->st_time)));
$stc = nl2br(escape($mt->st_content));

//START EMAIL
User::sendNewticket($send_to, 'Maintenance Ticket ' . Input::get('st_id'), <<<TEXT
Hello -<br><br>
TEXT
        . Input::get('rec_message') . <<<TEXT2
<br><br>

<strong>Conversation:</strong><br><br>

$fn<br>
$time<br>
$stc<br>

TEXT2
);
```

It produced:

```html
Hello -<br><br>Got something<br><br>

<strong>Conversation:</strong><br><br>

Kitty<br>
November 05, 2014 - 12:00 am<br>
    Dear Judy,<br />
<br />
        Lorem Dipsum and all that jazz.<br />
<br />
        Toodles,<br />
            Kitty.<br>
```

Though I'm sure it'll look better with your data.

Edit: And as [Blizz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50158/blizz) very correctly points out below, if you save the `rec_message` into a variable, you can avoid the concatenation altogether:

```
$recMessage = Input::get('rec_message');
User::sendNewticket($send_to, 'Maintenance Ticket ' . Input::get('st_id'), <<<TEXT
Hello -<br><br>
$recMessage
<br><br>

<strong>Conversation:</strong><br><br>

$fn<br>
$time<br>
$stc<br>

TEXT
);
```

---

**Edit 2**: With the extra messages, you should use something like this to simplify the email:

```
$messages = '';
foreach($st_messages->results() as $mt)
{

    $fn = escape($mt->from_name);
    $time = escape(date("F d, Y - h:i a", strtotime($mt->st_time)));
    $stc = nl2br(escape($mt->st_content));

    $messages .= <<<MESSAGE

$fn<br>
$time<br>
$stc<br><br>

MESSAGE;
}

$recMessage = Input::get('rec_message');
User::sendNewticket($send_to, 'Maintenance Ticket ' . Input::get('st_id'), <<<TEXT
Hello -<br><br>
$recMessage
<strong>Conversation:</strong><br><br>

$messages

Thanks,<br>
Support Team

TEXT
);
?>
```

Which with some basic dummy text produces:

```html
Hello -<br><br>
Got something
<strong>Conversation:</strong><br><br>


Person<br>
November 11, 2014 - 12:00 am<br>
My message blah blah<br><br>

sdfasdf<br>
April 11, 2014 - 12:00 am<br>
My message asdfasdf blah blah<br><br>


Thanks,<br>
Support Team
```

Comment: If you would capture the output of `Input::get('rec_message')` in a variable as well before you start the `HEREDOC`, there would be no need to actually interrupt it.

Comment: Looks a lot cleaner :)

Comment: @MrLore I tried your method, and it worked as far as the code goes, but still received 3 multiple emails containing each reply from the conversation separately. I updated my question with full code and more detail.

Comment: @MrLore everything is working as it should, but can't seem to figure out how to get the 3 replies from the conversation into the email. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @echo Don't you just need to add the messages with their html together in this loop? `foreach ($st_messages->results() as $mt)` Then you'd have all the messages in a single variable.

Comment: Yes, but when I do this it sends 3 separate emails instead of one email with all the replies from the conversation.

Comment: @MrLore I added an update, if you could take a look if you get a chance, I would appreciate it.

Comment: @MrLore That worked great thanks so much!

Just curious though, so I can understand this better. How did the `$messages = '';` help solve the problem?

Comment: @echo It just allows us to build up the conversation so we can put all of them into the email with the one variable, it would be a real mess to try and concatenate three heredocs together with the for loop in the middle.